# Firebase Database getting Objects

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

so honestly I just feel stupid right now but I just don't get it...

I want to get one "User" Object from my Firebase Realtime Database, so I add an ValueListener, right?
I have a Method "getUser" which has "User" as returnvalue. In there I use this:

```
ValueEventListener valueListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                User u = snap.getValue(User.class);
                if(u.getEmail().equals(userEmail))
                {
                   //user = u;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    //Adding the Listener for Single Event
    fref.child("User").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueListener);
    //Using "u" here then
```

Now I don't see a good way get that User "u" out of there, how do I get it?

I know this should be basics, but I just don't get it..

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
private User targetUser;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    final ValueEventListener userListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userNameList = new ArrayList<>((ArrayList) dataSnapshot.getValue());
            for (User u : userNameList) {
                if (u.getEmail().equals(userEmail)) {
                    targetUser = u;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: Failed to load User list.");

        }
    };
    userlistReference.addValueEventListener(userListener);

    mUserListListener = userListener;
    //use targetUser reference but check if it is null(can be null)...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a CountDownLatch - this object will let you wait till the listener is actually invoked before returning the object :

```
private User getUser() {
    final User user = null ;
    final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
    ValueEventListener valueListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                User u = snap.getValue(User.class);
                if(u.getEmail().equals(userEmail))
                {
                    user = u;
                    break ;
                }
            }
            cdl.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            cdl.countDown();
        }
    };
    //Adding the Listener for Single Event
    fref.child("User").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueListener);
    try {
        cdl.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    }
    return user ;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work either , it get's block waiting for always in the cld.countDown()

Comment: @RobertoFernandez it's really blocked on `countDown()` ? Weird, I have never seen that. Normally it blocks on `àwait()`. Well that solution works for me...

Answer (score -1):

You just need to create  global variable on your class, like:

```
private User myUser;
```

Then inside your listener just do:

```
myUser = u;
```

This is the easiest way...